# Maximum update depth exceeded. infinite warning loop

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, infinite-loop

I want to get data from my local storage and store it in state so I don't have to refresh my page every time I want to update table. Here is my code I know I am doing some mistake here because I am learning react.js. I get this warning every second hundreds of time "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render."

```
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
    const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("value"));
    if (items) {
    setItems(items);
    }
    }, [items]);
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: You will have to practise state change and useEffect hook, your useEffect is getting called infinite times because... Find the reason yourself for better understanding of the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `useEffect` function starts an infinite loop. It calls `setItems`, but also depends on the items state so it sets the state indefinitely.

You can give `useEffect` an empty dependency array so it sets the `Items` only once on the first render.

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("value"));
    if (items) {
        setItems(items);
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: That messes with my code as I want to update the state on button click. As I am making a shopping cart webapp and want to add item or subtract item from local storage.

Comment: If you want to update on button click you need to have a click Event and a handlerFunction for the click Event that sets the state

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't name your variables the same, it makes the code harder to read and it's prone to error.

Then the answer to your problem with the useEffect is in your statement.
What makes a useEffect to re-render? A little bit more help, in JS does {} === {}?

Finally if you want to get what's in localstorage only when user log in or come back to the page it should only happen **one** time right?

Then you could have a event handler that adds to the state and updates the local storage with the new state (you have more than one option here).
Don't forget to clean the localstorage though in the case the user doesn't need persistence anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution 
PROBLEM:
As the items are already in the local storage the code will keep reading the values and keep returning the values. 
SOLUTION:
I update the state and the local storage in my handler function by finding the id of data stored in the local storage {something like this}

```
const addition = (item) => {
let index = items.findIndex((data) => data.id == item.id);
console.log(index, "index");
totalItems += item.total;
items[index] = item;
setData(items);
localStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify([...items]));
};
```